# How to read and parse.msg file in java and write that file into excel sheet

Tags: java, maven, parsing

I have .msg file in drive iam trying to read and parse that . sometimes it shows error on maven dependency

I have tried many times and didn't get the output ,sometimes it shows output but it is  not user understandable format.
Iam expecting that my file has to be read and parse that, that parsed file has to be write in Excel sheet divide the data with space.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please update your question with your code and describe where exactly you're hitting a problem.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your .msg file, and also code for what you already have tried? ".msg" could be everything. Also think if you could split this question into two: one for reading the .msg file and (maybe) another one for writing to Excel - probably you will find other questions for that Excel problem - read them first.